# Error while creating a polyline in Cesium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cesiumjs

I am using the following code to create a polyline in my ReactJs app. I am getting "DeveloperError: Expected value to be greater than or equal to0.0125, the actual value was 0" error message. Can someone please explain to me why am I getting this error.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var redLine = viewer.entities.add({
  name: "Red line on terrain",
  polyline: {
    positions: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([180,90, 180, -90]),
    width: 5,
    material: Cesium.Color.RED,
    clampToGround: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's a bug for cesium.

If you delete the code from lines 259 to 265 in the `EllipsoidGeodesic-0f41968b.js` file, You will find that your code will run normally.

[Screenshot of commented code in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVyzx.png)

I have encountered a lot of problem behaviors like this.

I don’t know if I comment out the related anomaly detection, what will happen to the code system operation.

I guess that under certain extreme conditions, it may affect the normal operation of the system.